# Google Chrome Calculator Gives Interesting Answers

Tags: google-chrome, calculator

I was troubling with my clients SQL database which is trying to figure out longer than 2 decimal problems. For fast result just copied 2 different SQL cell for subtraction process to Google Chrome bar. And that was an interesting result: [image: First result] I tried with dots too but noting happened.[image: With dots]. [image: Another Example]. For first i thought something wrong with my SQL database. Before I figure out something wrong with result, tried to fix SQL database. But then with another examples I just think something wrong with that calculator I guess. So I'm asking is there any option or if I'm doing something wrong.